# Numerical convolution in real space

Tags: python, convolution

I have asked a similar question before, but I will try to phrase it a little clearer this time.

I want to convolve image A with kernel B. These may be pretty big, typically a few 100 pixels on each side.

This would be fastest in Fourier space, but I want to do it in real space (because I want to account for missing pixels), so the most direct way. The discrete, 2D convolution is then

[image]

Now, there are several functions in Python that can potentially do this. My first question: Take `scipy.signal.convolve2d` for instance. I have had memory issues before; is there an efficient way to do this at all?

For example, suppose my input image A is 1000x1000 pixels and I want to convolve this with a kernel of, say, 120x120 pixels?

Edit: [Astropy](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.convolution.convolve.html#astropy.convolution.convolve) seems to be a package that does just what I want.

Comment: Is there a sample code of what you've tried before and a clear description of the errors you faced?

Comment: Do `A` or `B` have any special properties? Or are they both random images?

Comment: Remember, for `A.shape == (N,N), B.shape == (M, M)` you're looking at `O(N^2 M^2)` time complexity. You shouldn't need substantially more memory than the initial `A` used though

Comment: The best way would be to take the FFT of A and B, multiply the FFTs and then perform the IFFT on the product. There's no faster way in the original domain to do convolution, other than call convolove2d.

Comment: A and B have properties appropriate for my science case, but other than that they're just images. 
I was looking to implement it myself, but I found a package (astropy) that seems to have the functionality I'm looking for.

@TomKealy, yes I know that's the fastest way but I want to account for missing pixels which is better done in real space. Thanks!

Comment: @John You should have said you wanted to account for missing pixels! We could have been more help!

Comment: @TomKealy You are quite right, I thought it was sufficient to say I wanted to do it in real space, but giving the reason explicitly is not a bad idea ;) I'll edit the post.

Comment: @John Please post an answer if you do find one - it could be useful to somebody else.